# Opposite terminology of 'mount point'

Tags: mount, terminology

If you use `df -h`

```
Filesystem                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
source_ip:/foo/what-is-this-called       420G   69G  351G  17% /mount-point
```

If you mount a specific directory to a mount point, that's not a partition nor filesystem.
What's the exact terminology for the mounted directory source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the exact terminology for the mounted directory source?

I would say "source" is good enough. To emphasize its connection with `mount` you can say "mount source".

See [`man 8 mount`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html). The mountpoint is the *target*; the device-like argument is the *source*. Especially here:

> `--source device`
> If only one argument for the mount command is given, then the argument might be interpreted as the target (mountpoint) or source (device). This option allows you to explicitly define that the argument is the mount source.
>
> `--target directory`
> If only one argument for the mount command is given, then the argument might be interpreted as the target (mountpoint) or source (device). This option allows you to explicitly define that the argument is the mount target.

While "device" is not a good word for "not a partition nor filesystem", "source" sounds general.

Comment: `proc(5)` simply defines it as `mount source: filesystem-specific information or "none"`. Notice that that isn't always to first argument passed to `mount(2)` -- the filesystem have a hook to dynamically generate that info.